# Azure Mobile Services and Push Notification for Windows Phone 8

Tags: node.js, windows-phone, windows-phone-8, azure-mobile-services

I've got some issues with this code (part of scheduled job in Azure Mobile Services):

```
    var channelTable = tables.getTable('PushChannels');
    channelTable.read({
        success: function(channels) {
            channels.forEach(function(channel) {
                push.mpns.sendToast(channel.PushChannelUri, {
                    text1: "AppName:",
                    text2: "Update!"
                }, {
                    success: function(pushResponse) {
                        console.log("Push sent");
                    },
                    error: function(error) {
                        console.error("Error!");
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
```

My problems are:

- Push notifications are not arriving device
- console.logs are not displaying in "Logs" tab

Could someone help me?
Kind regards!

Comment: Can you `console.log` your channels (inside the first success function) to see if you have valid data there?

Comment: The problem was at previous parts of that code. This code is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is correct. Problem was in code before that script.
I'm sorry for unnecessary question :(